# Изменение Background в CalendarDayButton

Tags: wpf, xaml

У меня есть коллекция, которая хранит в себе даты и прочую информацию. Во View я создал Calendar и хотел отрисовать те даты, которые находятся в моей коллекции. Решил написать дата триггер для CalendarDayButtonStyle, но не могу придумать, как правильно его написать.

Пример кода:

```
<Calendar Style="{DynamicResource BaseStyle}"
          DisplayDateStart="03.01.2024" 
          DisplayDateEnd="03.31.2024"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <Calendar.CalendarDayButtonStyle>
        <Style TargetType="CalendarDayButton">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger >
                    
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Calendar.CalendarDayButtonStyle>
</Calendar>
```

Дополнительно поясню. В коллекции CalendarCollection.StartDate имеется дата, которую нужно указать в календаре на View путем изменения Background у CalendarDayButton.